# Is Google Voice available outside the United States?

Tags: google-voice

I live in Germany now. I got an invitation for Google Voice, but was unable to make use of it since my location was outside the U.S.

Any idea when Google Voice will start to become available in Europe? In Germany, for instance?

Comment: Is Google Voice actually a Web App? Or is it more a smartphone app?

Comment: Definitely a web-app; with a smartphone component granted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Lifehacker covered this](http://lifehacker.com/5349506/make-free-voip-calls-from-google-voice) - you require a US number to terminate calls to, however you can set up a SIP based one that can be used to receive calls anywhere you have an Internet conncetion.

Comment: Wouldn't that violate their TOS?

Answer (score 2):

They haven't yet announced anything regarding Google Voice outside of the US

> Thanks for visiting Google Voice.
>   We're not yet open for users outside
>   the US, but are planning to expand our
>   service to additional countries in the
>   future.

Though there are rumours that they have been experimenting with integrating Google Voice into Gmail, perhaps as a feature for Chrome OS

Comment: @tealhill The image was posted way before we had imgur uploading and everything. But in general your suggestion is a good idea.