# Error in setting up Google Voice upgrade to use mobile phone number (outside the USA)

Tags: google-voice, voip

I receive the message:

```
Connection error. Please try again.
```

When in step 1 for the upgrade in Google Voice to use my mobile phone number. This error appears although I have inserted my phone number in various ways. This is being done from the UK. Is this service only for USA users possibly?

Comment: As far as I know, Google Voice is still a U.S.-only service. See: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/181/google-voice-outside-the-united-states

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Voice is a US only service for now.

> **Choosing an international number**
>
> It's not currently possible to select an international Google number or to forward your calls to an international number.

From [Google Voice Help](http://www.google.com/support/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115072)